# Failing Rails test based on lack of set session variable - how to set in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following very simple test which has always passed.

```
  test "should get index" do
    sign_in @user 
    get companies_url
    assert_response :success
  end
```

However, I'm now receiving the following error.

```
Error:
CompaniesControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:53:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2582383126246718868_70101260952060'
    test/controllers/companies_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:CompaniesControllerTest>'
```

What I've changed in my app is that I've built a sidebar (which I load via `application.html.erb` so it's loaded on all views (new, show, edit), which lets a user switch between various companies they "own" - which changes a session variable which we use to alter the content of the sidebar.

If we dig into the line that seems to be failing `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:53` this is how it looks:

```
<div class="list-group-item">
   <%= link_to 'Company', company_path(session[:current_company]) unless current_user.companies.empty? %>
</div>
```

If I remove this `link_to` line then the tests pass.

My guess is that the show view is trying to load, including the sidebar which doesn't have a `session[:current_company]` set so the view crashes. However, in Rails 5.2 you cannot set/test session variables as far as I understand, so I'm wondering what the best way for me to set the testing up to make this pass? I do set a value for this session within my `application controller` a user signs in though:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    # Set a default current company scope for a use after signing in
    session[:current_company] = current_user.companies.first.id unless current_user.companies.empty?
    companies_path
  end
```

Perhaps in the `link_to` from from within the sidebar I could add a default value to make sure we're always sending in a company, regardless of whether it's the `session[:current_company]` or not?

Answer (score 0):

Altering the line to skip creating the link if there is no session variable present

```
<%= link_to 'Company', company_path(session[:current_company]) unless current_user.companies.empty? || !session[:current_company] %>
```

Seemed to do the trick and make all the tests pass. Would love some feedback on whether this is a good solution or not though! :)